# Binary representation of powers of 3

Tags: nt.number-theory

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113760/binary-representation-of-powers-of-3) at Mathematics Stack Exchange but since I didn't got a satisfactory answer I decided to ask it here as well.

We write a power of 3 in bits in binary representation as follows.
For example $3=(11)$, $3^2=(1001)$ which means that we let the $k$-th bit from the right be $1$ if the binary representation of this power of 3 contains $2^{k-1}$, and $0$ otherwise.

1. Prove that the highest power of 3 that has a palindromic binary representation is $3^3 = (11011)$.
2. Prove that $3 = (11)$ is the only power of 3 with a periodic binary representation (in the sense that it consists of a finite sequence of $1$s and $0$s repeated two or more times, like "$11$" consists of two repetitions of the bitstring "$1$").

Comment: computer checking


Comment: Once 1 is established, 2 follows pretty easily.  You might try showing that powers of 3 mod some higher power of 2 provide a block towards being a palindrome.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.27

Comment: @Gerhard: how knowing the last few letters of a word you can prevent the word from being a palindrome?

Comment: I don't know how.  There is some literature on how close a power of 3 can be to a power of two, but I am unfamiliar with it.  The only other idea I have is to consider factors of 2^k + 1, and consider certain combinations of those, but that looks even less likely of an in.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.27

Comment: I'm going to leave the following nice fact here as there's a non zero chance it's related to the proof of 1 above: Let $f:\Bbb N\to\omega^{<\omega}$ send a natural number to the lengths of consecutive ones and zeroes in its representation, e.g. $f(27)=f(11011_2)=(2,1,2)$ then it can be proven that the representation of the periodic string of $-3^{-n}\in\Bbb Z_2$ is of period $2$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.  For example $-\frac1{27}=\overline{000010010111101101}_2\mapsto(\overline{4,1,2,1,1,\text{  }\color{red}{4,1,2,1,1}})$

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extended hint for proving 2 (an almost complete proof is in the Update below). If $3^s$ base 2 is periodic, then you can represent it as $u(1+2^m+2^{2m}+...+2^{(t-1)m})=u\frac{2^{tm}-1}{2^m-1}$ for some numbers $u,m,t$. Therefore if $q_n(x)$ denotes the $n$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), then $q_{tm}(2)$ must be a power of 3 (as a divisor of $3^s$). But it looks like $q_n(2)$ is never 0 modulo 9 (this should be possible to prove rigorously but I do not have time). Hence $q_{tm}(2)$ must be equal to 3 or 1 which gives a bound on $s$.

**Update** Since $2^m-1=0 \mod 9$ only when $m=0 \mod 6$. it is enough to consider $q_{6k}(2)$. Since $2^3=-1 \mod 9$, we only need remainders of cyclotomic polynomials modulo $x^3+1$ with coefficients modulo 9. Here are all 50 of them  $$ \begin{array}{l} 1,3,{x}^{2},8x,8{x}^{2},1+8x,5+5{x}^{2},x+1,x+8,x+8
{x}^{2},\\\ 4x+5{x}^{2},{x}^{2}+1,1+8{x}^{2}+8x,2+3x+2{x}^{2},
2+5x+4{x}^{2},2+8x+{x}^{2},2+{x}^{2}+7x,\\\ 2+2{x}^{2}+8x,2+6
{x}^{2}+7x,3+x+8{x}^{2},3+5x+3{x}^{2},\\\ 3+6x+2{x}^{2},3+2
{x}^{2}+7x,4+6x+3{x}^{2},4+7x+4{x}^{2},4+2{x}^{2}+5x,4
+3{x}^{2}+5x,\\\ 4+4{x}^{2}+6x,5+2x+7{x}^{2},5+4x+4{x}^{2}
,5+4{x}^{2}+5x, \\\ 6+2x+6{x}^{2}, \\\ 6+4x+5{x}^{2},6+7x+2{x}^{
2},6+5{x}^{2}+3x,6+6{x}^{2}+4x,\\\ 6+7{x}^{2}+3x,7+2x+6{x}
^{2},7+4x+7{x}^{2},\\\ 7+6{x}^{2}+3x,8+2x+7{x}^{2},8+6x+8{
x}^{2},8+8x+{x}^{2},
\\\ 8+7{x}^{2}+x,8+8{x}^{2}+2x,{x}^{2}+x+1,{x}
^{2}+8x+1 \end{array}$$ None of these polynomials become 0 when evaluated at $2 \mod 9$.

As for the last claim about the size of $q_{mt}(2)$: every root of the cyclotomic polynomial is on the unit circle, so the values at 2 grow with the degree.

This almost completes the proof of 2 (one needs to show that the set of 50 polynomials is complete, but that can be done by induction).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative (and complete) proof of 2. Following Mark Sapir, we show that the only solution of
$$ \frac{2^{tm}-1}{2^m-1} = 3^r $$
in positive integer triplets $(t,m,r)$ is $(2,1,1)$ and $(2,3,2)$. I am sure this was written down before, by the way.

Our main tool is the observation that $\mathrm{ord}_{3^n}(4)=3^{n-1}$ when $n\geq 1$ (in other words $2$ is a primitive root modulo $3^n$), which implies that $v_3(4^k-1)=1+v_3(k)$. The observation follows from $4^{3^{n-2}}\equiv 1+3^{n-1}\pmod{3^n}$ when $n\geq 2$, which in turn can be proved by induction or by the binomial theorem.

In the diophantine equation $r\geq 1$, hence $tm$ is even. If $m$ is even, then
$$ r=v_3\left (\frac{2^{tm}-1}{2^m-1}\right)=(1+v_3(tm))-(1+v_3(m))=v_3(t), $$
so that $t$ is divisible by $3^r$. This is a contradiction:
$$  3^r=\frac{2^{tm}-1}{2^m-1} > t \geq 3^r, $$
which proves that $m$ is odd and $t$ is even. In that case $4^m-1\mid 2^{tm}-1$, and
$$ \frac{2^{tm}-1}{4^m-1} = 3^s $$
for some $0\leq s\leq r$. As before
$$ s=v_3\left (\frac{2^{tm}-1}{4^m-1}\right)=(1+v_3(tm))-(1+v_3(m))=v_3(t), $$
so that $t$ is divisible by $3^s$. This is a contradiction when $t\geq 4$:
$$  3^s=\frac{2^{tm}-1}{4^m-1} > 4(t/2-1)\geq t \geq 3^s, $$
which proves that $t=2$. Now the original diophantine equation becomes
$$ 2^m+1=3^r,$$
where $m$ is odd. Then $1+v_3(m)=v_3(4^m-1)=r$, so that $m$ is divisible by $3^{r-1}$. It follows that $1+2^{3^{r-1}}\leq 3^r$. It is easy to see that this holds only for $r=1$ and $r=2$, which yields $m=1$ and $m=3$, respectively.

Comment: Alternatively, one can shorten the analysis using the following theorem of Bang: $2^n-1$ has a primitive prime divisor except for $n=1$ and $n=6$. 

Comment: @Anonymous: Thanks for the very relevant comment!